# 2010 Contact Us Form Webpart

Tags: 2010, form

im trying to implement a Contact Us Form Webpart on my Sharepoint 2010.
I am very new to webdesign and sharepoint.

Simple as it sounds it has 3 Textboxes Name, email, Message.
It has the Send the entered Data to my email.

I have the HTML code, but now i need a function that collects data  and send to my email.
How do i do that in sharepoint?

If it is not possible, can u tell me how to save the Data in a Shrepoint List?

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="contactUs" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="name">Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>


<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td> 
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">   
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: where is the php form located?

Comment: I have the PHP in a 2nd File.

Comment: i want to insert a webpart (HTML Form Web Part) in sharepoint, but there is only space for html code...what should i do with the php file?

Comment: one option is, first you create a list, and then you can Create a custom new item form using SharePoint designer. In this case you won't have to write code for saving the data to list. Then for sending email you can use designer workflows on List. Follow this link for creating workflows  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671(v=office.15).aspx]

Answer (score 1):

Even easier way would be.

Just create a custom SharePoint list and add your three fields: name, email, message. SharePoint will generate the new form, edit form and display form all for you. If you want to customize it so it contains some (validation) logic, you have the option to modify the form in InfoPath designer. Video tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ailu8LWjd10

I would simply create a Script Editor webparts with a "Contact us" button that opens your Contact us newform.aspx page in a modal dialogue window.

Put the following code in a function that's called from your button and change the options.url pinpointing the newform.aspx page.

```
//Using the DialogOptions class.
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

options.title = "My Dialog Title";
options.width = 400;
options.height = 600;
options.url = "/_layouts/DialogPage.aspx";

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx

Also, please don't try to use PHP in SharePoint. Two different technologies on a fundamental level. You should focus on one of them, not try to combine both.

Comment: Before I forget, in your target url, don't forget to add "?isdlg=1" at the end. This will strip the page from all it's SharePoint UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing in your case is to create the existing page in aspx and put in the layouts folder. In Sharepoint add a Page Viewer Webpart and link to this page . In the aspx, you can send email or save to a list.

Of course there are couple of other ways also